# Connecting stdout to stdin of the same process in Linux

Tags: stdout, stdin, capture

I'm writing an app that (ab)uses an APL engine, libapl.so.  The library contains a mechanism to allow me to capture results, but some stuff it dumps to stdout and stderr.  So my question is, is there way a to capture stuff written to stdout rather than having it go to a screen, get piped to another process, or some such?  Is there a way, for example, to connect stdout to stdin of the same process?  I've tinkered with pipe2(), dup(2), and various bits of weirdness in GTK+/Glib, but I haven't hit the right incantation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more poking--at least one solution seems to be to create a fifo, open() it twice, once for reading, one for writing, and dup2() the writing fd to the stdout fd.  This results in writes to stdout going through the fifo pipe where it can be read by the application.  (Thanks for some inspiration by someone named Hasturkun, almost 7 years ago.)

Here's a bit of demo code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char tname[64];
  sprintf (tname, "/tmp/testpipe%d", (int)getpid ());
  int rc = mkfifo (tname, 0666);
  if (rc != 0) {
    perror ("Creating fifo");
    return 1;
  }

  int temp_in_fd  = open (tname, O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY);
  if (temp_in_fd < 0) {
    perror ("Opening new input");
    return 1;
  }
  int temp_out_fd = open (tname, O_NONBLOCK | O_WRONLY);
  if (temp_out_fd < 0) {
    perror ("Opening new output");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *temp_in  = fdopen (temp_in_fd,  "r");
  if (!temp_in) {
    perror ("Creating new input FILE");
    return 1;
  }
  FILE *temp_out = fdopen (temp_out_fd, "w");
  if (!temp_out) {
    perror ("Creating new input FILE");
    return 1;
  }

  dup2 (fileno (temp_out), STDOUT_FILENO);

  printf("Woot!");
  fflush(stdout);

#define BFR_SIZE        64
  char bfr[BFR_SIZE];
  ssize_t sz = fread (bfr, 1, BFR_SIZE, temp_in);
  fprintf (stderr, "got %d bytes: \"%s\"\n", (int)sz, bfr);

  fclose (temp_out);
  fclose (temp_in);
  unlink (tname);
  return 0;
}
```